# Simplify an inequality with probabilities

Tags: probability

I've been stuck trying to simplify the following inequality or awhile now:

$$(1-\epsilon)P(A) + \epsilon > \frac{(1-\epsilon)P(A \cap B) + \epsilon}{(1 - \epsilon)P(B)},$$

with $0<\epsilon<1$, $P(A) < 1$ and $P(B)>0$. I'm trying to show that $\epsilon$ is less than some quantity involving only probability values, but I've been unable to isolate $\epsilon$ successfully. I think I might just be missing a substitution trick or something like that.

Comment: What are the conditions on $\varepsilon$. Is it strictly between zero and one. Could $\mathbb{P}[B]=0$? Could $\mathbb{P}[A]=1$? Are $A$ and $B$ independent? If yes this is always true. If not please explain what assumptions are you using.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Edited, thanks.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ independent? Could $\mathbb{P}[A]=1$?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be independent. Let us assume $P(A)<1$.

Comment: That is OK: if $\mathbb{P}[A]=1$ the condition cannot hold anyway. It would reduce to $1>1/[(1-\varepsilon)\mathbb{P}[B]]$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't give a very good answer (which makes me feel a little better about potential problems!). Basically you should end up with a quadratic inequality but it doesn't seem to give a very nice answer.

Let $e:=\varepsilon$, and $a:=\mathbb{P}[A]$, $b:=\mathbb{P}[B]$ and $c:=\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]$.

Multiply both sides by $(1-e)b>0$
$$
\begin{align*}
(1-e)b((1-e)a+e)&>(1-e)c+e
\\ \Rightarrow (b-be)(a-ae+e)&>c-ce+e
\\ \Rightarrow ab-abe+be-abe+abe^2-be^2-c+ce-e&>0
\\ \Rightarrow \underbrace{[ab-b]}_{=:A}e^2+\underbrace{[b+c-2ab-1]}_{=:B}e+\underbrace{[ab-c]}_{:=C}&>0 
\end{align*}$$
This is a quadratic inequality $Ae^2+Be+C>0$. Note the $e^2$-coefficient is $ab-b=b(a-1)<0$ and so we have a $\bigcap$-quadratic which is positive *between the roots*. We must find the roots therefore of $Ae^2+Be+C$ which might be easiest found by formula. Assume for the moment that $a=\mathbb{P}[A]\neq 0$.

Unfortunately the roots:

$$e_{\pm}=\frac{-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A},$$

do not appear to simplify nicely, and the best we seem to be able to do without looking at redundancies (perhaps $e_-\leq 0$ and so we have $0<\varepsilon<e_+$ or maybe $e_+\geq 1$ and so we just have $e_-<\varepsilon <1$ (probably not both)) is

$$e_-<\varepsilon <e_+.$$

If $a=\mathbb{P}[A]=0$, then going back to the original inequality we end up with

$$(1-\varepsilon)\mathbb{P}[B]>1,$$

which is impossible. A similar implication holds when $a=1$.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent we have $c=ab$ and it can be shown that we must have

$$\varepsilon<1-\frac{1}{b(1-a)},$$

which implies that

$$\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}<b(1-a),$$

which is impossible. This suggests the inequality never holds. I will leave the proof of that down to others. Note $\varepsilon=1$ leaves the inequality undefined but $\varepsilon=0$ is equivalent (I think) to

$$\mathbb{P}[B]>\mathbb{P}[B|A],$$
that is the inequality holds if the event $A$ occurring makes $B$ less likely. Perhaps such calculus comes into the analysis of $e_{\pm}$.